# composer nested require "no matching package found"

Tags: github, composer-php

I've created two testing repositories on github. [composer-test](https://github.com/tarach/composer-test) and [composer-test-inc](https://github.com/tarach/composer-test-inc) than I create two packagist entries [tarach/composer-test](https://packagist.org/packages/tarach/composer-test) and [tarach/composer-test-inc](https://packagist.org/packages/tarach/composer-test-inc)

After calling:

> $ composer require -vvv tarach/composer-test-inc:v1.0-alpha
>   I receive fallowing response:

```
$ composer require -vvv tarach/composer-test-inc:v1.0-alpha
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (CWD): hg branch
Executing command (CWD): svn info --xml
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
./composer.json has been created
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (CWD): hg branch
Executing command (CWD): svn info --xml
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014-07.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014-10.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-01.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-04.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json from cache
Downloading http://packagist.org/p/tarach/composer-test-inc$93dc775f482417914700941d53672a4e763c0d54604fe4fda2346134b51359d5.json
Writing C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-tarach$composer-test-inc.json into cache
Reading C:/Users/tarach/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-tarach$composer-test.json from cache
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for tarach/composer-test-inc v1.0-alpha -> satisfiable by tarach/composer-test-inc[v1.0-alpha].
    - tarach/composer-test-inc v1.0-alpha requires tarach/composer-test v1.0-alpha5 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

Earlier I tried to add zf2 framework components just to to see how it deals with requirements from other repositories and it doesn't. I've removed it from dependencies. Also after execution I used

```
$ composer clearcache
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Composer reads packages from packagist. When your packages don't live on packagist, but on github instead, you have to configure the [VCS package](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs).

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/igorw/monolog"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-bugfix"
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work,
Problem 1
    - Installation request for tarach/composer-test-inc v1.0-alpha -> satisfiable by tarach/composer-test-inc[v1.0-alpha].
    - tarach/composer-test-inc v1.0-alpha requires tarach/composer-test v1.0-alpha5 -> no matching package found.

Comment: Just to make sure: You didn't just copy the example in your composer.json and ran update again, did you?

Comment: Nope: https://github.com/tarach/composer-test-inc/blob/master/composer.json
https://packagist.org/packages/tarach/composer-test-inc